# How to solve refresh div situation?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

When I tried to refresh my controller view my page reload itself inside of the page with this code

```
 $(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#deneme').load('/veri/index/'); }, 500);
});
```

How can I solve this situation I attached as png ... [image: Here is situation]

Comment: `$('#deneme').load('/veri/index/ #deneme');`

Comment: dear freddomn, I have also situation like my load page always changing according to id number as /veri/index/1 how can I entered this 1 number to the load page it can be 2 - 3 or 4 it should do it automatically